# Was using .bind but now haved to use .delegate... have tried .undelegate?

Tags: jquery-selectors

**Heres the jsfiddle, [jsfiddle.net/kqreJ](http://jsfiddle.net/kqreJ)**

So I was using .bind no problem for this function but then I loaded more updates to the page and found out that .bind doesn't work for content imported to the page but just for content already on the page! Great!

So I switched it up to .delegate which is pretty cool but now I can't figure out how to .bind .unbind my function the way it was???

**Function using .bind which worked perfect... except didn't work on ajax content.. :(**

```
$('.open').bind("mouseup",function(event) {
var $this = $(this), handler = arguments.callee;
$this.unbind('mouseup', handler);
var id = $(this).attr("id");
var create = 'nope';

    var regex = /\d+$/,
    statusId = $('#maindiv .open').toArray().map(function(e){
        return parseInt(e.id.match(regex));
    });

var divsToCreate = [ parseInt(id) ];

$.each(divsToCreate, function(i,e)
{
    if ( $.inArray(e, statusId) == -1 ) {
        create = 'yup';
    }
});

        if( create == 'yup' ) {
            if(id) {
                    $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "../includes/open.php",
                    data: "post="+ id,
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(html) {
                    $('.open').html(html);
                    $this.click(handler);
                    }
                    });
            }
        }

});
```

**New function using .delegate that is not binded and creates multiple instances?**

```
$('#maindiv').delegate("span.open", "mouseup",function(event) {
var $this = $(this), handler = arguments.callee;
$this.unbind('mouseup', handler);
var id = $(this).attr("id");
var create = 'nope';

    var regex = /\d+$/,
    statusId = $('#maindiv .open').toArray().map(function(e){
        return parseInt(e.id.match(regex));
    });

var divsToCreate = [ parseInt(id) ];

$.each(divsToCreate, function(i,e)
{
    if ( $.inArray(e, statusId) == -1 ) {
        create = 'yup';
    }
});

        if( create == 'yup' ) {
            if(id) {
                    $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "../includes/open.php",
                    data: "post="+ id,
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(html) {
                    $('.open').html(html);
                    $this.click(handler);
                    }
                    });
            }
        }

});
```

I've spent hours trying to figure this out because I like learning how to do it myself but I had to break down and ask for help... getting frustrated!

I also read that when your binding and unbinding .delegate you have to put it above the ajax content? I've tried using .die() and .undelegate()... Maybe I just don't know where to place it?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [`undelegate`](http://api.jquery.com/undelegate/)

It does to `delegate` what `unbind` does to `bind`.

In your case, I think it'd be something like:

```
$('#maindiv').undelegate("span.open", "mouseup").delegate("span.open", "mouseup" ...
```

Then you can drop the `$this.unbind('mouseup', handler);` within the function.

Comment: Wouldn't it go where $this.click(handler); is? $('#maindiv').undelegate(".open", "mouseup");

Comment: Guilty of not looking thoroughly in the code! But you don't have to do it at the success of evry ajax call. Do it once in dom ready and any new content added through ajax will be hooked up properly. I need to take your code and format it little bit to be able to pinpoint, but you get the idea.

Comment: Mr. chief, would I have to place the $this.unbind('mouseup', handler); above the ajax call or same place I had $this.click(handler); when the function worked perfect with using .bind("mouseup...

Comment: Super weird that .bind worked perfectly but because I haved to be able to have the "load more" option I can't use it... :(

Comment: Its still creating multiple instances??? Where exactly would I place the .unbind call do I still need the $this.unbind('mouseup', handler); toward the top of the function?

Comment: Can you format your code a bit more? If can create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) that reproduces your isseu, it'd be much easier.

Comment: I'm trying to create a jsfiddle for you now to show you... few more mins... thanks Mrchief.

Comment: And what exactly is the flow? Like what should happen after appending div? What does the click do?

Comment: On "mouseup" its just supposed to create another box and highlight it if you click on that link or id# again!

Comment: Okay well the jsfiddle demo I put up works perfect... but on my site... does not work... should I put the .bind or .undelegate after or before the ajax call like above?