# Learning .delegate() on function... Can't use .bind

Tags: jquery-selectors

**Heres the jsfiddle, [jsfiddle.net/kqreJ](http://jsfiddle.net/kqreJ)**

So I was using .bind no problem for this function but then I loaded more updates to the page and found out that .bind doesn't work for content imported to the page but just for content already on the page! Great!

So I switched it up to .delegate which is pretty cool but now I can't figure out how to .bind .unbind my function the way it was???

```
$('#maindiv').undelegate(".open","mouseup").delegate(".open","mouseup",function(event){
var $this = $(this), handler = arguments.callee;
$this.unbind('mouseup', handler);
var id = $(this).attr("id");
var create = 'nope';

    var regex = /\d+$/,
    statusId = $('#maindiv .open').toArray().map(function(e){
        return parseInt(e.id.match(regex));
    });

var divsToCreate = [ parseInt(id) ];

$.each(divsToCreate, function(i,e)
{
    if ( $.inArray(e, statusId) == -1 ) {
        create = 'yup';
    }
});

        if( create == 'yup' ) {
            if(id) {
                    $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "../includes/open.php",
                    data: "post="+ id,
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(html) {
                    $('.open').html(html);
                    $this.click(handler);
                    }
                    });
            }
        }

});
```

You can see by the demo that it still creates multiple instances and isn't binding? Racked my brain trying to figure this out.

Comment: Can you post your code as it was with bind? or at least explain why you need to delegate or undelegate? Personally despite it being slower, just use live if it reduces your headaches.

Comment: .live doesn't work like .bind did, you can see how it was with .bind at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7251440/was-using-bind-but-now-haved-to-use-delegate-have-tried-undelegate ... Im loading more content via ajax to the page and .bind doesn't work on New content via ajax...

Comment: I need the function to create one new instance based on the id# then be able to click back on that id# if selected. When I used .bind it worked perfect but can't use .bind for ajax content. Click, opens new box only once, click another opens new box... user needs to be able to click on box again to select!

Answer (score 0):

Change `bind` to [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) and change nothing else... see if it works.
[`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) binds dynamically loaded content as well like `delegate`.
to unbind `live` I believe you use [`die`](http://api.jquery.com/die/).

**Update**

[This is how I would do it](http://jsfiddle.net/kqreJ/13/) assuming that all you want to do is `onClick` add a div if it doesn't already exist on the page and if the div does exist highlight it. I had to throw out your old code, it was too confusing, I went strictly by your requirement.

Keep in mind that since delegate is dynamically, it is bound to your selector, remove the class or change the id and binding is automatically removed from that class. In my example I have 2 delegate methods. Basically by changing the class I change the function being called.

Comment: `.live()` is slower than `.delegate()`!

Comment: Refer to this post, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7251440/was-using-bind-but-now-haved-to-use-delegate-have-tried-undelegate asked yesterday but had no success? stuck on this one! :(

Comment: yeah, but depends on how much content there is and if performance is really an issue... he had it working with bind, if changing it to live does what he wants then keep it simple.

Comment: .live creates multiple instances too... would rather use .delegate if possible, just can't figure out how to bind unbind like it was?

Comment: Can someone try to edit the jsfiddle to get it working? I've tried several times... no luck!

Comment: Have you looked at the jsfiddle I put up, http://jsfiddle.net/kqreJ ... Click on YUP to see whats happening.

Comment: I'd love to help brandon but I just don't understand what you are trying to achieve. Can you describe what the behavior should be or the functionality you are trying to achieve is?

Comment: Hey Ali, you can see at http://jsfiddle.net/kqreJ/ that when you click on yup... it creates a new box more than once. I need it to create a box one time per link and then highlight when you click on the same link!

Comment: [This is how I would do it](http://jsfiddle.net/kqreJ/13/) assuming that all you want to do is `onClick` add a div if it doesn't already exist on the page and if the div does exist highlight it. I had to throw out your old code, it was too confusing, I went strictly by your requirement.

Keep in mind that since delegate is dynamically, it is bound to your selector, remove the class or change the id and binding is automatically removed from that class. In my example I have 2 delegate methods. Basically by changing the class I change the function being called.